# Why is this not a POD?

Tags: c++, data-structures

This is about [`std::is_pod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod), which detects whether a template is a *plain old data type* or not.

See the following code:

```
struct A {
public:
    int m1;
    int m2;
};

struct B {
public:
    int m1;
private:
    int m2;
};

struct C {
private:
    int m1;
    int m2;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_pod<A>::value << '\n'; // true
    std::cout << std::is_pod<B>::value << '\n'; // false
    std::cout << std::is_pod<C>::value << '\n'; // true
}
```

The 3 structs all look like POD to me. But apparently `struct B` is not.
I don't understand why. To me, they all have a trivial constructor, move and copy operator. Destructor is certainly trivial too.

I blame it on using 2 access specifiers, but I can't find information about this.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod

Comment: For those of us to lazy to click on @juanchopanza's link, POD = plain old data type

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the standard (**9 Classes [class]**, emphasis mine):

> A *standard-layout class* is a class that:
>
> ...
>
> — ***has the same access control*** (Clause 11) ***for all non-static data members***,
>
> ...

and

> A *POD struct* is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and ***a standard-layout class***, and ...

Your hunch is correct, because `B.m1` and `B.m2` are both non-static and have different access control.